# how to load image in react (getting error module not found)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am trying to show multiple image using `map` function but getting this error

**Cannot find module '../../assets/images/logo-full.png'**

**Code which is working is fine in render method**

```
{[require('../../assets/images/logo-full.png')].map((i)=><img key={i} src={i}></img>)}
```

**Code which is not working  in render method and getting above error and why ??**

```
{['../../assets/images/logo-full.png'].map((i)=><img key={i} src={require(i)}></img>)}
```

why require is need in array element not in src?
[image]

Comment: it seems that the problem is about when the images get loaded. The first method is working because it is done at compiled step. The second one is not working because it is called when react renders and I think images are not loaded yet into bundle

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a variable to require. It needs to know at compile time for require to work. It's explained in the docs. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the images are in an array and you need to render the images by running a map on your array. So the path of the image must also be present in the array.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        imageArr:[{'id':1,source:'pathofimage1'},{'id':2,source:'pathofimage2'}]
    }
}


render(){
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.imageArr.map((item,index)=>{
                 return (
                     <div key={index}>
                     <img src={item.source} alt="image" />
                     </div>
                 )
            })
        </div>
    )
}
```